# Javascript: IF statement to change colour of text based on seconds

Tags: javascript

So i'm creating a timer and so far it does what it needs, displays the correct time between the two clicks of OK's, but now i want into change the output colour to green if it's below 0.5 seconds, i've tried below to do this but the colour doesn't change any solutions would be helpful.

Extra: I would also like to have Else IF statement for 0.5-1 seconds to be orange and anything over 1 second as red. Any guidance would be great

```
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();

alert("Press \"OK\" to start the timer.");
var starttime = Date.now();


alert("Press \"OK\" to stop the timer.");
var stoptime = Date.now();
var seconds_between = (stoptime - starttime) / 1000;
alert(seconds_between + " seconds");


var phrase1;
phrase1 = " seconds.";

var message;
message = seconds_between + phrase1;


if (seconds_between < 0 || seconds_between > 0.50) {
    message.fontcolor("green");
}


canvas.drawString(message, 10, 10);
canvas.paint();
```

Comment: You have a... *peculiar* coding style...

Comment: @nnnnnn There is apparently a nonstandard `fontcolor` method. All it does it wrap the string in a font tag. I don't know if that works with canvases in this manner.

Comment: I've got something even better: convert the 0-1 range of values into a continuous color gradient by using hsl.

Comment: @TimSeguine - Ah yes. I'd forgotten about those string methods. I'll delete my previous comment. (Although even if wrapping the string in a `<font>` tag worked with canvas drawing, the code would still need to be `message = message.fontcolor("green");` - but of course that won't actually work with a canvas...)

Comment: i'm new to all this Kroltan so i'm probably doing it wrong that's why it looks "peculiar", my teacher is also useless

Answer (score 1):

```
if (seconds_between < 0 || seconds_between > 0.50) {
    message.fontcolor("green");
}
```

needs to be

```
if (seconds_between > 0 || seconds_between < 0.50) {
    message.fontcolor("green");
}
```

Comment: Alright made those changes but the text still isn't showing as green.